# Need function to add increasing values of Dates

Tags: javascript, date

im looking for a function to add the value of the previous day to each next day.

I have following array:

```
{x: "8.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "9.9.2021", y: 33},
{x: "10.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "11.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "12.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "13.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "14.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "15.9.2021", y: 8},
{x: "16.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "17.9.2021", y: 99},
{x: "18.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "19.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "20.9.2021", y: 113},
{x: "21.9.2021", y: 57},
{x: "22.9.2021", y: 16},
{x: "23.9.2021", y: 0},
...
```

And im looking for something like this:

```
{x: "8.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "9.9.2021", y: 33},
{x: "10.9.2021", y: 33},
{x: "11.9.2021", y: 33},
{x: "12.9.2021", y: 33},
{x: "13.9.2021", y: 33},
{x: "14.9.2021", y: 33},
{x: "15.9.2021", y: 41},
{x: "16.9.2021", y: 41},
{x: "17.9.2021", y: 140},
{x: "18.9.2021", y: 140},
{x: "19.9.2021", y: 140},
{x: "20.9.2021", y: 253},
{x: "21.9.2021", y: 310},
{x: "22.9.2021", y: 326},
{x: "23.9.2021", y: 326},
...
```

That is what i tried but that froze my page

```
const add = (array) => { 
  let newArray= orders; 
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
      newArray[i] = { x: orders[i].x, y: orders[i].y + orders[--i] && orders[--i].y, }; } 
   return newArray; 
  };
```

Didn't find any solutions yet. The solution should be as simple as possible.

Comment: _The solution should be as simple as possible._ What have you tried so far? What went unexpected? And your example is not clear at all.

Comment: I didnt found any solutions yet, tried to loop and add the value of the before index. The new Array should contain the values of the old array but all values before that index added to the value.

Comment: Did you try to write a code for this?

Comment: const add = (array) => {
    let newArray= orders;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      newArray[i] = {
        x: orders[i].x,
        y: orders[i].y + orders[--i] && orders[--i].y,
      };
    }
    return newArray;
  }; --- That is what i tried but that froze my page.

Comment: Great, you should edit your question and include what you have tried in there. It will be easier for people to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the array, and add the values of y

```js
const data = [{x: "8.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "9.9.2021", y: 33},
{x: "10.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "11.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "12.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "13.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "14.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "15.9.2021", y: 8},
{x: "16.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "17.9.2021", y: 99},
{x: "18.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "19.9.2021", y: 0},
{x: "20.9.2021", y: 113},
{x: "21.9.2021", y: 57},
{x: "22.9.2021", y: 16},
{x: "23.9.2021", y: 0}]

const incremented = []
data.forEach((el, index) => {
  index === 0 ? incremented.push(el) : 
  incremented.push({...el, y: el.y + incremented[index-1].y})
})

console.log(incremented)
```